# How to write translated MediaWiki articles through the api using Translate extension?

Tags: api, localization, internationalization, mediawiki, machine-translation

I write hundred of articles into a MediaWiki (version 1.20.2) through its API using a self-programmed PHP script that depends on [WikiMate](https://github.com/hamstar/Wikimate). At the moment, the articles are only written in English. But I want to translate them using [the Translate extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aTranslate), so I have to approve every single article for translation.

For every article there is already an English and a French document, so is there any automated way to write articles in English (default) and the translated article (in French) at once using the API? The Translation should be compatible to the Translate extension.

Comment: Oh, and if it's not a secret, could you tell us on which site did you use it? We care about our users :)

Comment: It is a private wiki. You can not access it without a password.

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you mean that you already have source pages and translations, and want to move them to the Translate system? See instructions for migration to Translate: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:Extension:Translate/Page_translation_administration#migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I got things to work. You can copy the method `execute()` from `SpecialPageTranslation.php` to your custom class. This method will mark an article as translatable. Simply pass it the title of your desired article by instantiating a new `Title` object with `$title = Title::newFromText( 'Title_of_my_article' );`. Copy all the methods referenced by `$this` to your custom class as well. E.g. the method `$this->markForTranslation(..)` and its dependencies.

After calling the `execute()` method, an article is marked for translation so you can commit the translated article. I simply do this by giving the English-translated article the names `Title_of_my_article/1/en` and `Title_of_my_article/en` and commit them using the default MW API. (Be aware that `1/en` marks the translated section that you commit, so you will commit the whole article just as a translated section)

Sadly, the Translate extension is poorly documented so it is very hard to understand how things work.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "approve every single article for translation"? To do the "mark for translation" action, which adds the <!--T:1--> tags? Currently there's no web API to do this, unfortunately.

If you are very sure that the pages in both languages have a very similar structure, you can try writing your own script that would import them chunk by chunk, but there are no clever built-in options for that, either.

If you code any solutions for that, it would be very nice of you to share them :)

(Comment: I am one of the developers of the Translate extension.)

Comment: Yes, I mean that "mark for translation" action. I also thought of dividing the pages automatically, but I am not sure if there is an adequate heuristic because the pages do not have exactly the same structure. IMO the only solution would be telling the Translate extension to translate a full page at once instead of hacking it up, at least unless anybody hit the "mark for translation" action to edit the translation. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: No, not really. The main point of the extension is breaking up the text into small pieces and translating it piece by piece. Coordinating two existing texts is not something that the extensions knows how to do currently. I guess that putting two whole texts as translations of each other is slightly better than nothing, because at least it gives you a comfortable language switcher using the &lt;languages /> tag, but it's really a minor thing.

Comment: So how can I set two whole texts as translations of each other using the Translate extension?